# Удаление части текста между двумя известными символами

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

У меня имеется переменная `$text` с текстом, в котором в нескольких местах есть HTML комментарии `<!--- комментарий --->`.

Мне нужно от них избавиться. Я пробую так:

```
while (strripos($text,"<!---") != FALSE) {
    $one = strripos($text , "<!---" );
    $two = strripos($text , "--->" );
    $two = $two + 3;
    $nedle = substr($text, $one, $two);
    $text = str_replace($nedle, "", $text);
}
```

Но почему-то этот код не всегда корректно работает: удаляет не все комментарии.

Есть ли способ улучшить мой скрипт или другое решение данной задачи?

Comment: Да, есть: перестаньте пользоваться ручным разбором HTML, возьмите нормальный парсер. Думаю, что ваша проблема описана [здесь](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Расскажите о своей _настоящей_ задаче: зачем вам выкусывать HTML-комментарии?

Comment: Там просто есть дальше функция которая из текста делает превью обрезая его до длины 300 символов и добавляя к нему "..." и иногда она обрезает комментарий на половину оставляя его не закрытым в итоге при выводе текста плывет верстка(

Comment: Стойте-стойте! То есть вы кладёте **чужой HTML** на свою страницу? И у вас ещё никто не применил XSS и не увёл пользователей? Сообщаю вам, что у вас гораздо большие проблемы.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

preg_replace Вам в помощь. Примерно так:

`$new = preg_replace('/<!---.*?--->/is', '', $old);`

Comment: то что надо спасибо) мне казалось самому что через регулярное стоит но не мог подобрать нормальное выражение!

Answer (score 1):

А мне кажется лучше без регулярок:

```
$new = substr($old, strpos($old, '<!---'), strripos($old, '--->'));
```

Comment: Проверьте на тексте: `<p> Выход там ------></p><!--- exit button --->`